# how to automate calendar for date of birth by using show date picker in robot framework

Tags: css-selectors, robotframework

I want to automate calendar for date of birth but don't know how to do so.
kindly help.

```
[Arguments]    ${date_of_birth}
Click Element    id= xpath:/html/body/ion-modal/app-add-customer-popup/ion-content/div/div/div/form/div/div/div[6]/div/input

Select Date from Picker
    [Arguments]    ${date}
    ${year}     Split String    ${date}  
    ${day}    Set Variable    ${year[2]}
    ${month}    Set Variable    ${year[1]}
    ${year}    Set Variable    ${year[0]}
    Click Element    css=#ion-overlay-2 > app-add-customer-popup > ion-content > div > div > div > form > div > div > div:nth-child(6) > div > input
    Input Text    css=.1993    ${year}
    Input Text    css=.10    ${month}
    Click Element  xpath:/html/body/ion-modal/app-add-customer-popup/ion-content/div/div/div/form/div/div/div[6]/div/input
```

Comment: Date pickers are often unique and there is not one solution that works for all. What is wrong with your code? Only obvious thing is that you do not enter day value.

Comment: Hi Pekka thanks for the support. I have automated the date of birth from calendar. issue with my code was not entering the date as per the format means usually we put the date in  yyyy-mm-dd format but in my case it was mm-dd-yyyy. so earlier i was passing in yyyy-mm-dd format and due to this i was facing the issue.